# Search in Javascript object from array of properties and compare them to a value

Tags: javascript, typescript

Best explanation of my question will be with with an example. I have an array of object, something like this: `[{a:"a",b:"",c:"c"}, {a:"a",b:"b",c:""}, {a:"",b:"b",c:"c"}, {d:""} ]` and `[a,b]`
First I want to check that objects in the first array contains the properties from second and after that to check if they are empty string ( or undefined ) to set them to let say "something". Final version:
`[{a:"a",b:"something",c:"c"}, {a:"a",b:"b",c:""}, {a:"something", b:"b",c:"c"}, {a:"something", b:"something", d:""} ]`
NOTE: I have working code, but looks ungly and I want to find a better approach

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better placed on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you double check your expected answer? `d` doesn't make sense in last obj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a unique set of keys and map the values for new entries.

```js
const 
    array = [{ a: "a", b: "", c: "c" }, { a: "a", b: "b", c: "" }, { a: "", b: "b", c: "c" }, { d: "" }],
    keys = ['a', 'b'],
    result = array.map(o => Object.fromEntries(
        [...new Set([...Object.keys(o), ...keys])].map(k => [k, keys.includes(k) ? o[k] || 'something' : o[k]])
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A solution without `Set`

```js
const 
    array = [{ a: "a", b: "", c: "c" }, { a: "a", b: "b", c: "" }, { a: "", b: "b", c: "c" }, { d: "" }],
    keys = ['a', 'b'],
    result = array.map(o => Object.assign(
        {},
        o,
        ...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] || 'something' }))
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr1 = [{a:"a",b:"",c:"c"}, {a:"a",b:"b",c:""}, {a:"",b:"b",c:"c"}, {d:""} ];
let arr2 = ['a','b'];

for (let element of arr1) {
    for (let key of arr2) {
        if (arr2.includes(key) && !element[key]) {
            element[key] = 'Something';
        }
    }
}
console.log('arr1 = ' + JSON.stringify(arr1));
```

Answer (score 1):

We can take advantage of the fact that empty strings and `undefined` are falsy.

There are shorter ways to do this, but the following is one way you could approach it. For each object in the array, we iterate over the desired keys and set them to `'something'` if its value is falsy; otherwise, we set it to itself.

```js
const objects = [{a:'a',b:'',c:'c'}, {a:'a',b:'b',c:''}, {a:'',b:'b',c:'c'}, {d:''}];
const keys = ['a', 'b'];

objects.map(o => {
  for (const key of keys) {
    o[key] = o[key] || 'something';
  }
  return o;
});
```

If, however, your values can be `false`, `0`, `NaN`, etc., we need to explicitly check.

Answer (score 1):

> check that objects in the first array contains the properties from second

1. Loop through every Object in the "first" Array
2. Loop through every key in the "second" Array
3. Check that every key is present at least once in the Object's values

> check if they are empty string ( or undefined ) to set them to let say "something"

1. Loop through every Object in the "first" Array
2. Loop through every key/value pair in the Object
3. If one of the values is an empty String or `undefined`, overwrite the value to be `"something"`

```js
const arr = [{a:"a",b:"",c:"c"}, {a:"a",b:"b",c:""}, {a:"",b:"b",c:"c"}, {d:""}];
const required = ["a", "b"];
const replacement = "something";

const hasRequired = arr.every(e => required.every(req => Object.values(e).includes(req)));

const transformed = arr.map(e => {
  return Object.entries(e).reduce((res, [k, v]) => {
    if (v === "" || v === undefined) {
      e[k] = replacement;
    }

    return res;
  }, e);
});

console.log(hasRequired);
console.log(transformed);
```